# How to change the background image of TD?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my codes:

JS/jQuery:

```
function RefreshImage(){
    var form_data = {
        ID: $('#ID').val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "submit/image.php",
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#IMG').css('backgroundImage', "url('images/+data+')");
        }
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td background="images/default.jpg" id="IMG"></td> 
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="ID" value="4">
```

CSS:

```
#IMG{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    width:99px; height:99px;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    vertical-align:text-top;
}
```

My codes is failed because it just change to black image. But on the response, it show the exact value of the image name that I am requesting, but it is failed because it just change to black.

Advance THANKS.

Comment: There is no TD attribute "background". Define the background image in your CSS file. If I remember correctly, jQuery relies on predefined CSS properties before manipulating them.

Comment: Quotes are sensible creatures, don't forget them :)

Answer (score 5):

`background-image` is the correct CSS property, not `backgroungImage`. *UPDATE* As pointed out in the comments, 'backgroundImage' is valid as it references the javascript property.

You also have an issue with concatenation on `data`:

```
 $('#IMG').css('background-image','url(images/' + data + ')');
```

Also, remove the `background` attribute on your `<td>`, and apply it via css:

```
 #IMG{ background-image: url(images/default.jpg); }
```

Comment: jQuery accepts both the CSS property of `background-image` and the JS equivalent property of `backgroundImage` as strings so either would work. The concatenation is the problem

Comment: Huh, I learn something new every day. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
$('#IMG').css('backgroundImage',"url('images/+data+')")
```

to

```
$('#IMG').css('backgroundImage','url(images/'+data+')');
```